# Como substituir o valor da variavel global, criada como ponteiro, em C++?

Tags: c++

Eu tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
// Programa: String de funcao pra outra
// Objetivo: Pegar uma string referenciada como parametro e jogar para outra
// funcao Autor: Raul Chiarella Data: 20/Outubro/2022

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; // Coloco essa linha pra nao ter q digitar std::

// Variaveis: Usei tipo string, biblioteca <string>
// Global Variables
string *g_IP;
string *g_MAC;

// Prototypes - Coloque as funcoes q vai usar aqui
void networkInfo();
void sendInfo();

// Functions.
void networkInfo() {
  g_IP = new string;
  g_MAC = new string;
  *g_IP = "String Teste";
}

void sendInfo() { 
  
  cout << "Test: " << g_IP; }
    
int main() {
  networkInfo();
  sendInfo();
}
```

Onde a funcao networkInfo() eu quero atribuir novos valores a variavel global, e sendInfo() preciso ler esses novos valores e printar na tela.

Porem o output ta saindo assim:

Test: 0x1cb8eb0

Ta saindo literalmente isso.

Comment: Esse não é um programa C++. Crie uma struct Info com `network()` e `send()` dentro. E claro `MAC` e `IP`. E não use nada global. Nunca.

Comment: Como assim? Tá literalmente rodando num "Repl" C++ no meu Replit... https://replit.com/@HorselessName/2Strings#main.cpp

Comment: E o que significa?

Comment: Significa que é um programa C++. ._.

Comment: Que significa um _Tá literalmente rodando num "Repl" C++ no meu Replit..._? Não sei o que é isso. Imagino que seja um programa `C++`, mais próximo de `C` no entanto. E também não entendi esse comentário.

Comment: Mano vc tá dizendo q esse não é um programa C++ e eu estou te afirmando o contrário hahahah

Comment: Você escreveu um programa `C` usando `cout` e `string` para transformá-lo em `C++` e de fato não entendi os comentários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código algo assim serviria:

Troque

```
void networkInfo()
{
    g_IP  = new string;
    g_MAC = new string;
    *g_IP = "String Teste";
}

void sendInfo() { cout << "Test: " << g_IP; }
```

Por

```
void networkInfo()
{
    g_IP  = new string("169.254.10.10");
    g_MAC = new string("00:00:3D:12:34:56");
}

void sendInfo()
{
    cout << "MAC Address: '" << *g_MAC << "' IP : '" << *g_IP
         << "'\n";
}
```

E assim aloca as duas strings. Em `main()` sempre apague o que alocou:

```
int main(void)
{
    networkInfo();
    sendInfo();
    delete g_IP;
    delete g_MAC;
    return 0;
}
```

E vai ver na saída

```
MAC Address: '00:00:3D:12:34:56' IP : '169.254.10.10'
```

### EXEMPLO

O modo como escreveu é desenconrajado desde sempre em `C++` e em especial pós 1998. Provavelmente um programa assim não seria aceito em empresas e custaria boa parte de sua nota em escolas. Em particular o uso de `raw pointers` e de variáveis globais em geral não é aceito há décadas. É como te disse um programa `C`.

Considere algo como:

```
struct Info
{
    string IP;
    string MAC;

    Info() : Info("169.24.10.10", "00:00:3D:12:34:56"){};
    Info(string mac, string ip) : IP(ip), MAC(mac){};
    friend ost& operator<<(ost&,const Info&);
};
```

Que é uma maneira comum de escrever isso desde sempre mas em especial desde 2011.

#### main.cpp para esse exemplo

```
int main(void)
{
    Info uma;
    Info outra("00:1a:3f:12:34:56", "192.168.0.1");

    cout << uma;
    cout << outra;
    return 0;
}
```

O programa cria 2 estruturas e pode ver umas diferenças entre `C++` e `C`. Ao declarar `uma` sem parâmetros `MAC` e `IP` ficam com os valores padrão, mas `outra` permite passar os valores.
Em `C++` qualquer operador pode ser redefinido então é comum redefinir `<<` para a classe e assim poder usar direto o nome da `struct` em `cout`. Claro que é bem conveniente porque se pode personalizar a exibição da classe.

#### saída desse exemplo

```
MAC Address: '00:00:3D:12:34:56' IP : '169.24.10.10'
MAC Address: '00:1a:3f:12:34:56' IP : '192.168.0.1'
```

#### O programa todo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using ost = std::ostream; // pra encurtar o nome...

struct Info
{
    string IP;
    string MAC;

    Info() : Info("169.24.10.10", "00:00:3D:12:34:56"){};
    Info(string mac, string ip) : IP(ip), MAC(mac){};
    friend ost& operator<<(ost&,const Info&);
};

int main(void)
{
    Info uma;
    Info outra("00:1a:3f:12:34:56", "192.168.0.1");

    cout << uma;
    cout << outra;
    return 0;
}

ost& operator<<(ost& sai, const Info& info)
{
    sai << "MAC Address: '" << info.MAC <<
           "' IP : '" << info.IP << "'\n";
    return sai;
}
```

Em 2022 provavelmente seria mais cômodo e versátil trocar

```
    sai << "MAC Address: '" << info.MAC <<
           "' IP : '" << info.IP << "'\n";
```

usando a ultra inconveniente sintaxe do `cout` por algo como

```
    sai << std::format("MAC: '{}' IP: '{}'\n", info.MAC, info.IP);
```

usando `std::format` de `C++20`

E logo mais `C++23` deve incluir `print()` e `printl()` usando a sintaxe de `format` no header `print`

Comment: Valeu, deu boa...